# Generating class diagram from source code

Tags: c++, uml, enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect and I wish to generate some class diagrams for a specific set of C++ objects within a massive project. By right clicking on a particular model and choosing Code Engineering from the context menu I can import the entire source directory for the project and generate class diagrams for all objects in the project.

I can also simply generate a class diagram for a single source file.  However what I'd ideally like is to generate individual class diagrams for a particular set of files within the project (for example ones which only contain the text SNMP within their names).  Can anyone help me apply this filter as the class diagram for the entire project is too large and unwieldy to manage in any capacity.

Answer (score 1):

In Enterprise Architect once you have imported the entire model like you have already done you can create additional diagrams to show only the parts of the model you need.  In fact I consider this normal practice.

First create a new diagram with Add->New View -> Class View & diagram.

Then drag only the classes you want from Model in the Project Browser onto the new Diagram.

Answer (score -1):

If you comment your code using doxygen then you can generate these class diagrams automatically. Please look at our code at github/nvmecompliance/tnvme for example. I'm not sure if this directly applies to your case if the source code you are not going to modify..

Comment: One can use doxygen to generate class or call graphs without modifying the code.